# How do I know if I am using gitignore or gitignore_global?

Tags: git, gitignore

The title says all. Is there any command to know which gitignore I am using?

Answer (score 0):

Both the global and repo-specific gitignore rules will be applied.

GitHub has good info on this topic: https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files#global-gitignore